# Python difflib gnu patch compatibility

Tags: python, compatibility, patch, difflib

It's possible to create patch with python module difflib which is compatible with GNU patch?
I tried to use unified_diff and context_diff and also tried to specify lineterm as "\n" but I'm still gettings this error:

```
[intense@Singularity Desktop]$ patch diff.patch test.txt 
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
```

I used file.writelines(diff) to write patch into file (Piece of code http://pastebin.com/3HAWfwVf)

File test.txt:

```
Hello, this is test
blah
```

File test2.txt:

```
Hello, this is test
blah, dfsgjdfgj
lfkdjgkldfjgkldfjgkl
```

And generated patch:

```
--- /home/intense/Desktop/test.txt
+++ /home/intense/Desktop/test2.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,7 @@
-Hello, this is test
-blah+Hello,+this+is+test+blah,+dfsgjdfgj+lfkdjgkldfjgkldfjgkl
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use mercurials bdiff module, which is considerably faster than difflib.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use [python-patch](http://code.google.com/p/python-patch/) instead of the GNU patch utility to apply unified diffs,
2. **OR** use `diff -rNau dir-v1/ dir-v2/ > 1-2.patch` instead of difflib.